# How did the Romans salute the Republic?

Tags: classical-latin, history

Are there any known phrases that were used by Romans to celebrate or cheer for the Republic? Something like ***Ave Res Publica*** ?

Or maybe they'd cheer for something else, like for the Senate or for the Consuls themselves? Are there any such examples? If not, then, is ***Ave Res Publica*** grammatically acceptable?

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for the interesting question!